# I have a mirror modifier on and I want an object mirrored but two different parts

Tags: mirror

okay so my object is being mirrored from one side to the other, I would like the two objects seperate intead of just one mirrored object.

Comment: perhaps not clear enough, do you mean unclick the Clipping option in the modifier? Or apply your mirror then separate with P > Selection?

Comment: I have the mirror function on, I would like to seperate it and have the mirror be two parts so I can edit one side of it only. Not both sides.

Comment: please share some screenshots! Unable to understand what you mean!

Comment: so, apply your modifier, then select the part your want to separate, and press P > Selection

Comment: when I do that it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your object with Shift+D and apply interactive mirror, or Ctrl+M, to the duplicate.

Comment: Pretty much what Mirror modifier does. Note to apply scale and recalculate normals for the mirrorred part with this way as under the hood Interactive Mirror inverts scale.

Comment: You're welcome, Car00071